# addcallback ListenableFuture

Tags: java

I am trying to use ListenableFutues for the first time, getting an error while using addCallback method, Please help.

Attached is the snapshot of the code.
Error is:

```
error: <identifier> expected
      Futures.addCallback(futureRequest,new FutureCallback<T>() {
                         ^

error: <identifier> expected
      Futures.addCallback(futureRequest,new FutureCallback<T>() {
                                       ^
```

Comment: Can you add content of this screenshot here?

Comment: Added screenshot content

Comment: You have to wrap your code  inside one Method that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ListenableFuture Callback like below.

```
    import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    import com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback;
    import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
    import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
    import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService;
    import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;

    public class EventDriver<T> {
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

        public void prepare() {
            Callable<T> task = null; // Whatever task you need to assign
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

            ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executorService);
            ListenableFuture<T> futureRequest = service.submit(task);
            Futures.addCallback(futureRequest, new FutureCallback<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(T result) {
                    logger.info("Sucess..");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    logger.info("Failure..");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```